# have file tempfile2.gz (checked via file command) but gunzip/gzip -d does not work

Tags: linux, gzip

I had a file (was a text file at first), did `xxd -r` to it and saved it to tempfile2. Afterwards did `file tempfile2` and it wrote:

```
tempfile2: gzip compressed data, was "data2.bin", from Unix, last modified: Fri Nov 14 10:32:20 2014, max compression
```

I tried:

```
gzip -d tempfile2>tempfile3
gzip -d tempfile2.gz > tempfile3
gzip -d tempfile2.gz > tempfile3.gz
gunzip tempfile2
gunzip tempfile2.gz
gunzip tempfile2 > tempfile3
```

... all combinations possible.

neither of that worked. It either said no such file in directory or  `unknown suffix -- ignored`

Comment: What if you try to rename the file? Maybe there is a white space at the end of the file name you can check this using double quotes....

Comment: tried that already... file name has nothing to do with it (thnx for editing b.t.w, the format of adding code here is annoying)

Comment: cat -v tempfile2.gz | tail , what it returns (please dont use tail directly you not want this believe me).

Comment: @JuliePelletier Please look up what the `-r` option does to `xxd`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a `tempfile2.gz` you only have a `tempfile2`.

Decompress by doing

```
gzip -d  < tempfile2 > tempfile3
```

Normally gzip would expect a `.gz` file for decompression and so you can do

```
mv tempfile2 tempfile2.gz
gzip -d tempfile2.gz
```

which would give you an uncompressed `tempfile2`. Or you could do

```
mv tempfile2 tempfile2.gz
gzip -cd tempfile2.gz > tempfile3
```

the `-c` making sure the output is written to standard output. Or do

```
zcat tempfile2 > tempfile3
```

so you don't need to provide any options, for which picking the correct ones seem the source of your problems.